# How to check if Linq Expression value is null

Tags: c#, linq

I have a lambda expression `x => x.person.parent.Id == someId` and I want to check if `someId` is null or not. The issue I am facing is that `Id` property is a nullable integer (i.e. `int?`). This is my attempt but it does not work if property is nullable. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
    private static bool IsNullExpression(Expression exp)
    {
        if (exp is ConstantExpression constantExpression)
        {
            return constantExpression.Value == null;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void AddIfNotNull(Expression<Func<T, bool>> exp)
    {
        // convert expression to binary expression
        if (exp.Body is BinaryExpression binaryExpression && (IsNullExpression(binaryExpression.Left) || IsNullExpression(binaryExpression.Right)))
        {
            // there is a null in expression, we just found it
            return;
        }

        _list.Add(exp);
    }
```

Comment: May want to read the [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that people can really help, from this it's hard to determine what exactly you are trying to do and how to reproduce, for example any reason your not using `x => x.person.parent.Id.HasValue && x.person.parent.Id == someId`

Comment: Why not check before your linq query ? What is is the problem you are trying to solve ? May be it could be better or easiest to validate your variable before your linq query ?

Comment: Is `someId` a constant ? or a captured local ? `x => x.person.parent.Id == null` or `var someId = 0; x => x.person.parent.Id == someId `

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: `someId` is a variable of type `int?`. There is no error message. Code fails to find that `someId` was `null` and returns `false`

Comment: Then check `someId.HasValue`

`x => x.person.parent.Id.HasValue && someId.HasValue && x.person.parent.Id.Value == someId.Value`

Comment: are you sure it actually works for `int` ? Because in my testing it does not

Comment: I think under the hood of Linq expression, it does not assign null to nullable types.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several cases you don't handle.

Firstly, if the property and the value are of different types, the constant will be warped in a `Convert` LINQ node, (which is of type `UnaryExpression`) which you need to unwrap.

Secondly if we are dealing with captured variables, the compiler will generate an extra object and the variables will be transformed into fields on this object, and the expression that accesses the variable will be a member access to the constant that contains the capture object.

```
private static bool IsNullExpression(Expression exp)
{

    // If types are different  for example int and int? there will be an extra conversion expression, we need to unwrap this
    if (exp is UnaryExpression uExp) exp = uExp.Operand;

    // If we are dealing with a captured variable, then teh constant will be the capture object and the value is stored as a member on this object
    if (exp is MemberExpression mExp && mExp.Expression is ConstantExpression cExp)
    {
        object value = mExp.Member is PropertyInfo pInfo ? pInfo.GetValue(cExp.Value) :
            mExp.Member is FieldInfo fInfo ? fInfo.GetValue(cExp.Value) :
            throw new NotSupportedException();

        return value == null;
    }
    // If we use a simple constant, this is what will be called
    if (exp is ConstantExpression constantExpression)
    {
        return constantExpression.Value == null;
    }

    return false;
}

// Tested with the following
// Simple constant expressions
TestMethod(p => p.Id == 0);
TestMethod(p => p.Id == null);

// Capture a non null value 
int value = 0;
TestMethod(p => p.Id == value);
// Capture a null value 
int? nullValue = null;
TestMethod(p => p.Parent.Id == nullValue);


// Testing infrastructure
public static bool TestMethod(Expression<Func<Person, bool>> exp)
{
    // If we have a binary expression
    if (exp.Body is BinaryExpression binaryExpression && (IsNullExpression(binaryExpression.Left) || IsNullExpression(binaryExpression.Right)))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}
public class Person
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
}
```